# IndexedDB using YDN-DB: How to determine if an object store exists

Tags: javascript, indexeddb, ydn-db

Using IndexedDB for a local html5 app, and specifically the YDN-DB wrapper, I often need to query a store using dynamically obtained store names.
When the store does not exist, I come away with an error, and javascript execution aborts. The error looks like so:

```
Uncaught ydn.error.ArgumentException: Store "client_store" not found.
```

Of course, I know the store does not exist, but how best can I code to 'catch' this error more elegantly?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this little utility function:

```
function storeExists(name) {
    var exists = false;

    db.getSchema().stores.forEach(function (store) {
        if (store.name === name) {
            return exists = true;
        }
    });

    return exists;
}
```

**Execution**

```
storeExists('client_store');
```

Answer (score 0):

The best is you can avoid dynamically changing database schema.

You can also check existence of store name by checking in schema `db.getSchema().stores.contains('new store')`.

Comment: Thank you @Kyaw for the answer. However, this did not help much (yet!). `db.getSchema().stores` returns an array of all stores, but each one is an object that you have to query for `name` property. Iterating through them to get `if(store_exists)` doesn't seem trifle. So for now, the path I've chosen is: Make sure every possible store already exists in the schema (if a script is going to ask for it) even if it isn't required yet for storage. All the same, I do appreciate your consistent support.